# Magento 1.9.2.4 sub-category listing not working

Tags: magento-1.9, category, module, catalog, category-products

I managed to get sub-categories showing on the category page with images, but now since updating 1.9.2.1 up to 1.9.2.4 it no longer works. I cant imagine what may have changed and haven't altered anything.

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-listing-sub-categories-on-a-category-page.html#gref

Looks like the block code:

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" template="catalog/navigation/subcategory_listing.phtml"}}
```

in the static block just wont get executed. Any help please????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into `System->Permissions->Blocks` and add your block `catalog/navigation` in that list. I'm pretty sure that your problem will be solved.

Comment: You sir are fantastic, thank you for taking the time to help myself. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome !

Comment: I have a similar conundrum where I am trying to use this extension: magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/… but it wont work, Ive tried adding pcarousel/pcarousel to the block permissions list. worked in 1.9.2.0.1